# The infinitive of "уймитесь"?

Tags: выбор-слова, морфология

повернись - повернитесь - повернуться

ложись - ложитесь - ложиться

оглянись - оглянитесь - оглянуться

успокойся - успокойтесь - успокоиться

уймись - уймитесь - ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's "[уняться](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)". Well, usually the answer supposed to be somewhat wider, but in this particular case that's virtually all that can be said)

**UPD:** To make this answer slightly more informative, here's what worth to me mentioned. There's a bunch of verbs in Russian - [`понять`](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C), [`занять`](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C), `нанять`, `унять` etc. that have form with -йм: `пойми`, `займи`, `найми`, `уйми`.

Historically this is because `нять` is derived from Proto-Slavic `jęti`, which also reconstructed in form `*jьmǫ`.

Curious relevant fact: `понять` and `поймать` are actually related.

Comment: Oh yeah, a verb without a root. ))

Comment: @YellowSky well, it depends on how deep we want to go - there was some kind of root )

Comment: There is a humorous short story about verb "вынуть": https://quotesbook.info/parables/writing/Koren

Comment: "понять and поймать are actually related." - thinking pattern which perhaps is reflected in English "to grasp". Funny how those languages are so different in some aspects and so close in others.  PS. поиметь probably too

Comment: @Arioch yep, and you also can say in English "I didn't quite catch that" - and "catch" used as "understand" in this context.

Comment: and also "I've got it" - that very "поиметь" again :-D

Comment: @shabunc "I didn't quite catch that"--means (I didn't hear that), not (I didn't understand that.)

Comment: @VCH250 nope it means both - it's also about not understanding.

Comment: @shabunc It certainly does not mean both (Native language is English). You would have to add ( "catch your meaning", or some other phrase). Otherwise it's just asking the other person to repeat themselves.

Comment: @VCH250 you are wrong